# S3 bucket policy to grant/restrict access to a specific federated user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, active-directory, amazon-iam

I am looking for a S3 bucket policy which can grant/restrict specific federated users access to the bucket. Federated users in aws uses IAM roles. Is there some way I can limit the access to a user even if the user has assumed the role. Is there a way I can specify federated users in a bucket policy? Also the S3 bucket is in a different account.

Comment: If the federated user is assuming a role, have you tried specifying that role's ARN in the `Principal` field of the Bucket Policy? Or are you saying that you don't want to grant access to _everybody_ that uses the role, just that one user?

Answer (score 1):

When a user is assuming a role, they are assigned a `role-session-name`. This can be used to track the identity of the user assuming the role.

From [AWS JSON Policy Elements: Principal - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html):

> **Specific assumed-role user**
>
> ```
> "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::AWS-account-ID:assumed-role/role-name/role-session-name" }
> ```